# FileListBox to ListBox To Array

Tags: arrays, listbox

I am trying to create a file picker for a system I am doing - Please note that I am uing Indusoft Web Studio that has access to various DOTNET and activex controls.

So far I have managed the following:

1. Using a FileListBox to display contents of a folder
2. Then I can Click (Or Double Click) on it to shift the values into an array (And then some script incrementing the array index)

HOWEVER - I would like to have this more visual. - I would like to display the picked files in a ListBox - However I have NO IDEA how to go about this.

So my requirements:

Create a "Click to Add" "Click to Remove" functionality - See attached JPEG.

The list box values must also be loaded into a string array. - This is becaue this array in turn is linked to a TwinCat system which must process the file names.

Please guys - any help will be greatly appreciated.!

[Image showing exactly what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7xzR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This logic will take your existing array of files and put them into a ListBox and a tag String Array.  You can put this sub in the screen script and then trigger it via a MouseUp (or similar) event on the FileListBox object so it updates the ListBox automatically.  Alternatively, you could put it in a command if you want to wait for the user to finish selecting files before writing out to the String array tag.

```
    Sub UpdateListBox()

        ' SelectedFiles = Your existing array mentioned in Step 2 of the question

        ' Clear all items from the ListBox - otherwise the values will be appended and 
        '  the list will grow each time items are added
        $XRun("ListBox1", "Items.Clear")

        For i = 0 To $SelectedFiles->Size
            $XRun("ListBox1", "Items.Add", $SelectedFiles[i])
            $StringArray[i] = $SelectedFiles[i]
        Next

    End Sub
```